# Deploy Strapi app to Google App Engine with mysql database fails with server 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, strapi

I am trying to deploy my Strapi app with cloud sql database and I've done the steps in the provided tutorial:

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/google-app-engine.html

The problem is when deploying the app with "gcp-build": "strapi build" it completes successfully but when navigating to the url of the website it gives me 500 error :

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

Additional context:

my app.yaml ( changed database details ):

```
 runtime: nodejs14

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  DATABASE_NAME:  'name'
  DATABASE_USERNAME: 'root'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'password'
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: 'instanceName'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: 'instanceName'
```

my database file :

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: "default",
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: "bookshelf",
      settings: {
        client: "mysql",
        host:
          env("NODE_ENV") === "development"
            ? "127.0.0.1"
            : `/cloudsql/${env("INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME")}`,
        database: env("DATABASE_NAME"),
        username: env("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
        password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
      },
      options: {},
    },
  },
});
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "seth-backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "gcp-build": "strapi build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.9",
    "cron-parser": "^3.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.9.0",
    "knex": "0.21.18",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "puppeteer": "^10.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.0",
    "strapi": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-admin": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-i18n": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.3",
    "strapi-utils": "3.6.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "8a4924ef-8800-44ac-913c-1d6b7e7cb954"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

and when I try to deploy the app with "gcp-build": "strapi build && strapi start " it gives me the following error

NOTE: it tries to connect to database with 127.0.0.1:3306 as it is development server don't know why !!

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build ea12c6f6-e173-4c75-af51-0e0a330ba229 status: FAILURE
Error ID: 617e6b41
Error type: UNKNOWN
Error message: > seth-backend@0.1.0 gcp-build /workspace
> strapi build && strapi start

Building your admin UI with development configuration ...
\u2139 Compiling Webpack
\u2714 Webpack: Compiled successfully in 1.83m
[2021-07-01T16:56:44.111Z] debug \u26d4\ufe0f Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-07-01T16:56:44.112Z] error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at /workspace/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:68:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (/workspace/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:63:12)
    at create (/workspace/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:290:39)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! seth-backend@0.1.0 gcp-build: `strapi build && strapi start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the seth-backend@0.1.0 gcp-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2021-07-01T16_56_44_132Z-debug.log
Suggested improvements or fixes
-update the documentation to the new versions of the app and node
```

Comment: Have a look at this github link with a [similar case](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/2146).

Are you using the App Engine Flexible or Standard  environment? If it is Standard, please try to deploy it in Flexible environment. Also, please include the `npm` in your `package.json`

Comment: I was using standard enviornment .. I've tried to used flex and I think it will work but it gives me ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed.  Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Answer (score 1):

You have to set App Engine Deployer role in your IAM peermissions:

[image]